# Slow Page (css style breaks) Loading On IOS Devices

Tags: android, ios, iphone, css, ios7

I have developed a mobile based web site targeting all the phones and tablets. The page loads fine on android devices and phones. But the web site takes lots of time to load on the chrome browser on IOS devices(Iphone, Ipad) and when it does load the css styles break, there is no problem in opening the website in safari browsers on IOS. What is cause of this problem, is it the browser ?

I came across few articles which mentioned that there is problem with chrome on IOS, how can I fix this or is there a solution for this problem. Any answer will be helpful.

Thanks In Advance.